# Native dll built with /CLR flag containing a managed class

Tags: c++, clr, managed

I have a old native MFC/c++ dll I have managed to get it compiled with /CLR flag. 
Now I have added a managed C++/CLI class to the dll within a namaspace.

The header file is below, and the cpp file only has #include for the header file.
The native dll is a huge dll project with lot of un managed code, but it has only one managed c++ class like below.

When I add that dll as a reference to a .net winforms project I don't see that namespace / class, in the object browser,

and I get compile error for not finding the namespace "ShashiTest"

I am using Visual studio 2008.

Native dlls in mixed mode can not be added as reference to a managed project ?

Or am I missing something

Please help.

```
#pragma once
#using<mscorlib.dll>
#using<system.windows.forms.dll>
// Class derived from Forms

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

namespace ShashiTest {
/// <summary>
/// Summary for test
/// </summary>
   public ref class test
  { 
   public:
    test(void)
    {

    };
    void ShowMessage()
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Hello World");
    }
  };
}
```

When I simplified my problem..I created a fresh MFC dll and added a manged C++ class to it (same class as above) . Compiled with /CLR flag.

When I add this dll to winforms project and run it i get

System.BadImageFormatException. Any clue ?

However I see the class and the name space and winform project compiles fine unlike the problem I have the above.

Comment: This should work. Maybe you should show some code? Or use reflector to check the contents of your dll.

Answer (score 1):

`System.BadImageFormatException` is usually caused by having an `AnyCPU` .NET application reference a DLL containing 32-bit native code.  You get an error when running on a 64-bit platform, because the `AnyCPU` application runs as 64-bit, and can't load the DLL.  The fix for this is (easy) to mark the application as x86-only or (hard) to provide both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of all DLLs containing native code.

Of course, you could have some other problem.  Checking your DLL with Red Gate Reflector as suggested by @cdleonard in the comments is a great next step.  Or [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx), which is free.

Comment: Thanks That was my issue, I forced my .net application to x86 and problem went away.